# OneNote for Mac - how to open multiple Windows

Tags: macos, onenote

I have the latest freebie Microsoft OneNote for Mac, running on a Macbook Air with Mavericks 10.9.4.  Try as I might, I can't find out how to get it to open more than one window.  I'd like to be able to view 2 pages from the same section in a Notebook, or 2 pages from different Notebooks, but I can't work out how to do it.

Sorry if this is a repeat - I thought I'd posted it a few weeks ago but I can't find it in my "asked questions" list.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it isn't programming related.

Comment: Since this is a general software question (not specifically related to programming tools), I think it would fit in better on [su].

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This feature hasn't been ported to the Mac version of OneNote. It is a highly requested user feature on their feedback forum: https://onenote.uservoice.com/forums/256328-onenote-users/suggestions/6158369-allow-multiple-windows-on-mac